# Scipy ValueError: object too deep for desired array with optimize.leastsq

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-fitting, function-fitting

I am trying to fit my 3D data with linear 3D function Z = a*x+b*y+c. I import the data with pandas:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('3d_data.csv',names=['x','y','z'],header=0)

print(dataframe)

            x          y          z
0   52.830740   7.812507   0.000000
1   44.647931  61.031381   8.827942
2   38.725318   0.707952  52.857968
3    0.000000  31.026271  17.743218
4   57.137854  51.291656  61.546131
5   46.341341   3.394429  26.462564
6    3.440893  46.333864  70.440650
```

I have done some digging and found that the best way to fit 3D data it is to use optimize from scipy with the model equation and residual function:

```
def model_calc(parameter, x, y):
    a, b, c = parameter
    return a*x + b*y + c

def residual(parameter, data, x, y):
    res = []
    for _x in x:
        for _y in y:
            res.append(data-model_calc(parameter,x,y))
    return res
```

I fit the data with:

```
params0 = [0.1, -0.2,1.]
result = scipy.optimize.leastsq(residual,params0,(dataframe['z'],dataframe['x'],dataframe['y']))
fittedParams = result[0]
```

But the result is a ValueError:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array [...]
minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

I was trying to minimize the residual function to give only single value or single np.array but it didn't help. I don't know where is the problem and if maybe the search space for parameters it is not too complex. I would be very grateful for some hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fitting parameters to a function, you can use [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). Here's an implementation:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def model_calc(X, a, b, c):
    x, y = X
    return a*x + b*y + c

p0 = [0.1, -0.2, 1.]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(model_calc, (dataframe.x, dataframe.y), dataframe.z, p0)  #popt is the fit, pcov is the covariance matrix (see the docs)
```

Note that your sintax must be if the form f(X, a, b, c), where X can be a 2D vector (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372597/python-curve-fit-with-multiple-independent-variables)).

**(Another approach)**

If you know your fit is going to be linear, you can use `numpy.linalg.lstsq`. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html). Example solution:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import lstsq
A = np.vstack((dataframe.x, dataframe.y, np.ones_like(dataframe.y))).T
B = dataframe.z
a, b, c = lstsq(A, B)[0]
```