# Multi-variable nonlinear scipy curve_fit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I have been trying to fit my data to a custom equation.which is the following y=(a1/x)+a2*x2+b  with curve fit
i used curve fit with 1 independant variable it works perfectly but i cannot figure out how to use it with 2

```
def func (x1,x2,a1,a2,b):
    y=(a1/x)+a2*x2+b
    return y

x=df[["feature1","feature2"]].values
y=df["target"].values
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python curve\_fit with multiple independent variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372597/python-curve-fit-with-multiple-independent-variables)

Comment: no i saw it and it didnt work for my case