# Which library/function should I use to fit a multivariate polynom to my data?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-fitting

I have data that depends on 4 independent variables (x1,x2,x3,x4) and I need a model (available in Python) to evaluate f(x1,x2,x3,x4) outside the data points. In principle, if I set 3 of my variables as constant values I can always use a polynomial fit of a reasonable degree (<5) to interpolate the data in the remaining dimension so I would like to generate a function that is capable to interpolate in all dimensions at once using a multivariate polynomial fit. It must be noted that the underlying function is non-linear (meaning that I should expect terms of the form x1^n*x2^m where n,m are not 0). What do you recommend?

To illustrate I am including a small sample of data:

(Note that the fact that some variables appear to be constant is due to the fact that this is just a small sample)

```
x1  x2  x3  x4  f
15  10  5   3   0.621646
15  10  5   5   0.488879
15  10  5   10  0.490204
15  10  7   0   0.616027
15  10  7   0.5 0.615497
15  10  7   1   0.619804
15  10  7   3   0.614494
15  10  7   5   0.556772
15  10  7   10  0.555393
15  20  0.5 0   0.764692
15  20  0.5 0.5 0.78774
15  20  0.5 1   0.799749
15  20  0.5 3   0.567796
15  20  0.5 5   0.328497
15  20  0.5 10  0.0923708
15  20  1   0   0.802219
15  20  1   0.5 0.811475
15  20  1   1   0.822908
15  20  1   3   0.721053
15  20  1   5   0.573549
15  20  1   10  0.206259
15  20  2   0   0.829069
15  20  2   0.5 0.831135
15  0   7   1   0.240144
15  0   7   3   0.258186
15  0   7   5   0.260836
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do multivariate curve fitting use the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` function. It is well documented and there are multiple questions and answers on StackOverflow on using it for multivariate fitting.

For your case, something like this can help you start off

```
import numpy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Example function to fit to your data
def non_linear_func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return x[0] ** a * x[1] ** b + x[2] ** c + x[3] ** d 

# X is your multivariate x data
# f is your y data

# p0 is an initial guess for your a,b,c,d... in your fitting function
p0 = [1,2,3,4]

fitParams, fitCov = curve_fit(non_linear_func, X, y, p0=p0)
```

A couple of things to note, you need to make sure that the `X` and `y` you pass to `curve_fit()` have the correct dimensions. `X` must have dimensions of N x M, where N is the number of data points you have, and M is the number of independent variables you have. `y` should be of length N.

You must also define your fitting function based on the form that you would like, and try and give an initial guess, `p0`, for the parameters in the function to help `curve_fit` find the optimal values.

Hope that helps, there are lots of good answers on multivariate fitting with `curve_fit()` on StackOverflow (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372597/python-curve-fit-with-multiple-independent-variables) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372597/python-curve-fit-with-multiple-independent-variables)) and the [curve_fit documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) should be of help as well.